# Streamlining Bind Mounting for User Folders between Windows 10 and MX Linux 23.2

Tags: linux, windows-10, mount, ntfs, dualboot

I've successfully configured a shared partition between Windows 10 and MX Linux 23.2, ensuring strict mapping of user accounts in both operating systems. Steps such as creating the ntfs-formatted partition, relocating default save locations in Windows, creating UserMapping in Linux using `ntfsusermap`, and editing `/etc/fstab` for mounting the partition have been completed accurately. The shared partition now adheres to the structure `/SharedPartition/WinUsername/SysFolder/`, granting each Linux account access only to its corresponding Windows account.

The remaining task is to ensure that every system folder in Linux also saves to the appropriate folders on the shared partition. Unlike Windows 10, there isn't a straightforward method for this in Linux. I'm considering editing `/etc/fstab` to implement bind mounts, which would entail adding numerous lines like `/SharedPartition/WinUsername/SysFolder/ /home/lin_username/sys_folder none bind 0 0` (6 times the number of user accounts). Is this the most efficient approach for implementing bind mounts, or are there alternative methods that could streamline the process while maintaining strict user account mapping?

Any insights or alternative approaches would be highly valued. Thank you!